# How to display text around box?

Tags: html, css

here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/9y7d3124/1/, I'm trying to display red box in the right top corner, AND TEXT AROUND it, but if there too much text on the left box is moving below, if I set absolute position for box text is moving under the box, text is dynamic, because of it can't set it by margins or paddings, does anybody know a solution? Here html code:

```
<div class="left">asdfwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</div>
<div class=right></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class=right></div>
  <div  class="left">asdfwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a container to your elements:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="right"></div>
        <p>Some DescriptSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome DescriptionSome Descriptionion</p>
    </div>
```

and use the following css:

```
.right{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: right;
}


.content {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9y7d3124/5/

You can use overflow hidden of the variable width div. Notice the sequence of left and right divs, it's reverse.

```
<div class=right></div>

  <div  class="left">asdfwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</div>


.right{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float:right;
}

.left {
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```